# Is the function $\det : M_{2\times2}(\mathbb{F}) \rightarrow \mathbb{F}$ is a linear transformation ?.

Tags: linear-algebra

Is  the following statement is True/false ?

the function $\det : M_{2\times2}(\mathbb{F}) \rightarrow \mathbb{F}$  is  a linear transformation .

My attempt :  for  linear  $\det(A +B)  = \det A + \det B$ as im not getting  how  to check the  whether  this  is linear or not

any hints/solution will be appreciated

thanks u

Comment: Plug in some examples.  Try the identity matrix and the matrix with 1 in the top left and 0 elsewhere.

Comment: For what it's worth.... it's linear if and only if the matrices' size is one by one LOL

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint:

Try almost any example.  Start with obvious ones. Here’s one:

\begin{bmatrix}1&0\\0&0\end{bmatrix} + \begin{bmatrix}0&0\\0&1\end{bmatrix}= \begin{bmatrix}1&0\\0&1\end{bmatrix}

In fact, it seems you would have to try very hard to get an example that doesn’t disprove the statement.

Comment: thanks @rschwieb